# what's wrong with my shader using texture by through glUniform1i

Tags: opengl, glsl

in my texturing with GLSL program,just one texture bind to texture unit 0.such as following:

```
.......................
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLuint tid;
        glGenTextures(1, &tid);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tid);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, img.width, img.height, 0,
                     img.format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img.data);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

and then inform to frag shader through a uniform variable(as setUniform does),here's name is "texture0" corresponding  to my frag shader:

```
void CShader::setUniform( const char *name, int val )
    {
        int loc = getUniformLocation(name);
        glAssert();  //note!,my own assertion wrapping around glGetError.
              if( loc >= 0 )
        {
            glUniform1i(loc, val);

        } else {
            printf("Uniform: %s not found.\n",name);
        }
              glAssert();   //note!,my own assertion wrapping around glGetError.

    }
```

it is out of my expectation, it assert failed at last `glAssert()` line,and giving me `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` .what was wrong,doesn't my display card is supported for this operation?,it can't be,my `OpenGL` version is 3.x.  after few hours struggle, did a try commented the last `glAssert()`,but another assertion failed  at my gldrawelements call. obviously, i absolutely think that cause `gldrawelements` failed is `glUniform1i` failed. can someone give me suggestion.

**EDIT:**

from datenwolf  suggestion,here 's code for glAssert, it's very simple,just call glGetError once.

```
void _glAssert(const char * info, int line){
 char const* sz_GL_INVALID_ENUM="GL_INVALID_ENUM";
 char const* sz_GL_INVALID_VALUE="GL_INVALID_VALUE";
 char const* sz_GL_INVALID_OPERATION="GL_INVALID_OPERATION";
 char const* sz_GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY ="GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY";
GLenum result;
    if((result=glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR )
    {
        const char *  sz_result=NULL;
        switch(result)
        {
        case GL_INVALID_ENUM:
            sz_result = sz_GL_INVALID_ENUM;
        break;
        case GL_INVALID_VALUE:
            sz_result = sz_GL_INVALID_VALUE;
        break;
        case GL_INVALID_OPERATION:
            sz_result = sz_GL_INVALID_OPERATION;
        break;
        case GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
            sz_result = sz_GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
        break;
        }

        _assert(sz_result,info,line);
    }
}

#define glAssert() \
    _glAssert(__FILE__, __LINE__);
```

BTW，before i use glUniform1i call,everything works fine with my shader

```
attribute vec3 VertexPosition;
varying vec3 Color;
void main()
{
Color = vec3(0.5,0,0);
gl_TexCoord[0]  = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4( VertexPosition, 1.0 );
}


uniform sampler2D texture0;

varying vec3 Color;
void main() {

 vec4 texColor = texture2D( texture0, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
gl_FragColor= vec4(Color, 1.0)*texColor;
}
```

i have stripped out many code in shader to simplify the problem .

i'm Sorry that I don't describe this in detail. actually,my wrapper around opengl is very simple,no complex things with it, no multiple threads.

this is constructor used for loading texture and shader script into GPU,memory separately, then call "compileandlink" method to compile the shader script , and call setUniform immediately.

```
IEntity(const char * szvs,const char * szfs): m_shader(new CShader(szvs,szfs)){
         ...........................
}

CCube::CCube():IEntity("v_simple.glsl","f_simple.glsl") {
    ...................

        IMAGE img;
        img.Load("texture.bmp");
        img.ExpandPalette();

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLuint tid;
        glGenTextures(1, &tid);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tid);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, img.width, img.height, 0,
                     img.format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img.data);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        m_shader->compileandlink();
        m_shader->setUniform("texture0", 0);
}
```

**CShader::compileandlink method**

```
bool CShader::compileandlink(){
            if(m_vsscript == NULL || m_fsscript == NULL)
                return false;

            if(strlen(m_vsscript) <= 0  || strlen(m_fsscript) <= 0)
                return false;

            glShaderSource(m_vs, 1, (const GLchar **) &m_vsscript, NULL);
            glCompileShader(m_vs);

            glShaderSource(m_fs, 1, (const GLchar **) &m_fsscript, NULL);
            glCompileShader(m_fs);

            glAttachShader(m_program, m_vs);
            glAttachShader(m_program, m_fs);
            //glBindFragDataLocation(m_program, 0, "FragColor");
            glLinkProgram(m_program);
            glAssert();


            GLint status;
            glGetProgramiv( m_program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
            if( GL_FALSE == status ) {
            fprintf( stderr, "Failed to link shader program!\n" );
            GLint logLen;
            glGetProgramiv(m_program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,
            &logLen);

            if( logLen > 0 )
                {
                char * log = (char *)malloc(logLen);
                GLsizei written;
                glGetProgramInfoLog(m_program, logLen,
                    &written, log);
                printf("Program log: \n%s", log);
                free(log);
                }
            }


            return true;

    }
```

**CShader::setUniform method**, as i say before,it have  GL_INVALID_OPERATION result of "glGetError" after glGetUniformiv returned inside this method.

```
void CShader::setUniform( const char *name, int val )
    {
        int loc = getUniformLocation(name);
        glAssert();
        if( loc >= 0 )
        {
            GLint outval=-1;

            glUniform1i(loc, val);
            /*int tmploc =glGetUniformLocation(m_program, name);
            glGetUniformiv(m_program,
                            tmploc,
                           &outval);
            printf("Value is %d\n", outval);*/

        } else {
            printf("Uniform: %s not found.\n",name);
        }
        glAssert();
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately your code doesn't show a few vital things: First: How does glAssert look like? OpenGL errors stack and you have to call glGetError in a loop until it returns GL_NO_ERROR. If you don't do this, you'll get reported stale error state. Also it's not clear in which context instances of CShader operate. Mapping OpenGL into classes and instances is very hard and almost impossible to get right.

Comment: Well, binding OpenGL in a C++ wrapper does work quite well, and is really convenient. But indeed, we have to be extra careful about keeping the stacks clean while not adding too much extra opengl work to the functions. But overall I think it is a very good design approach, especially when multiple shaders and FBOs come into play.
Could you show us how and when you bind your shader as well. You'd be amazed how much trouble comes from such simple stuff ;)

Comment: Is the program in use before you set the uniform value(s)?

Comment: thank all you three guys reply. i have edited my post. to @datenwolf, geenux . as you've saw. my program is nothing more than allocate Cshader object on heap, and deallocate at destructor, also it is single thread,in ordered operation. to Brett Hale, no, before i set the uniform vlaue,i'm not draw anything.

Comment: @geenux: I bet your OOP wrapping falls apart as soon as you have multiple OpenGL contexts within a program, maybe even multithreaded, i.e. each thread has a different context bound. And to make matters worse, contexts can share their data containing objects (texture, vertex and pixel buffer objects). It gets crazy if you need to keep track of all of this. I've been down that road several times. Only recently I attempted writing a clean, fully functional OpenGL OOP wrapper and gave up.

Comment: @geenux: First you should really call glGetError in a loop in your glAssert method. Also you should call your glAssert right *before* you do anything with OpenGL to make sure you're not running into some issue created by previous OpenGL operations. Check that you're working on a clean slate! If you call this from a constructor it may be, that there's no valid OpenGL context bound at the time of calling; this is a common issue with OOP wrappers around OpenGL, the solution is to do non OpenGL initialization in the constructor and do OpenGL setup operations explicitly through a `setupGL` method.

Comment: hey,@datenwolf .it's me. i think your advice about designs is useful for me. i gonna do it on yours experiences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
m_shader->compileandlink();
m_shader->setUniform("texture0", 0);
```

This will not work, because [you can only set uniforms when there's an active program object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_%3a_common_mistakes#glUniform_doesn.27t_work). i.e., you need `glUseProgram(m_program)` before trying to set the uniform value. That's why there's no `program` parameter for the `glUniform` functions.

I don't understand: `int loc = getUniformLocation(name)`, since it *does* require the name of a linked program. The commented: `glGetUniformLocation(m_program, name)` is actually correct.

Comment: oh, so stupid am i.i forgot to bind current program object,after add next to "compileandlink" method,everthing works fine. really thank you remind me. @Brett Hale